# How netezza matches columns while doing insert into select from

Tags: sql, netezza

When I use:

```
insert into table2 select * from table1;
```

Does it match up table 1 and table2 by the relative order of columns or by the column names?

Comment: From my own humble experience, I would suggest you put column names explicitly to avoid making your code not working if any of the two tables columns have changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement:

```
insert into table2
    select *
    from table1;
```

Aligns columns by position, *not* by column name.  In most cases, you should be explicit about the names:

```
insert into table2(col1, . . . coln)
    select col1, . . . coln
    from table1;
```

Netezza is based on Postgres.  [Here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-insert.html) is the relevant documentation in Postgres:

> The target column names can be listed in any order. If no list of
>   column names is given at all, the default is all the columns of the
>   table in their declared order; or the first N column names, if there
>   are only N columns supplied by the VALUES clause or query. The values
>   supplied by the VALUES clause or query are associated with the
>   explicit or implicit column list left-to-right.

However, I believe this behavior is part of the ANSI standard.  All databases that I know of operate this way.

Comment: This is an old post, but i have a question. Does Netezza allow to Insert some columns using the select query from another table and some of the values as default parameters. An example of such a query would be as:

insert into table2(col1,col2,col3 . . . coln)
    select table1.col1,table1.col2,'default_value' . . . table1.coln
    from table1;

Thanks!

Comment: @Jenny . . . That is not correct syntax.  If you have a question, you should ask a *question*.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon. I figured it out.